# Partial/Custom sorting in R vector

Tags: r, sorting

I am trying to generate a 3 column array in R, with the following property-
1st column goes from 0 to 255, for a total of (256*256) times.

```
B_1 <- as.data.frame(rep.int(0:255,256*256))
```

3rd column has the exact same values as the first one, but sorted from least to greatest

```
B_3 <- as.data.frame(sort(B_1[,1],decreasing = FALSE))
```

But I cannot think of a simple algorithm for the column in between the two in which I want the following- Every value in B_2 should repeat for 256 sets of 0:255 in B1. In other words, as value increment in B_3, the value in B_2 is reset to 0, for 256 times. I can join the three vectors to make the array afterwards easily enough. The purpose is illustrated in the following piece of code.

```
j= 0
for (i in 1: 16777216){
  B_2[i,1]=j
  if(B_1[i,1]>B_1[i+1,1]){
    j = j + 1
   }
  if (j>255){
    j=0
  }

  }
```

But as you can imagine, for an array of this size, for loop is highly inefficient. I understand that tidyverse will probably have a method to do this easily, but I was hoping to find one within the base packages of R. Can this be done?

Comment: Might be a good idea to reduce the size of the arrays to something you can display in your question, and give an example output of the desired B_2, as it's not entirely clear (to me, at least) what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Reduced to a more manageable example, is this what you want?  `data.frame(B_1 = rep(0:3, 16), B_2 = rep(0:3, each = 4), B_3 = rep(3:0, each = 16))`

Comment: Ah, sorry, did not read your comment, before posting a similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you need.

```
B_3 <- as.data.frame(rep(0:255, each=255))
```

Comment: H 1, indeed, that is what I want.